# display the factors of given integer?

Tags: c

I am using code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

     int n,i;
     printf("enter an integer value:");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     if(n!=0)
     {
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
           if(n%i==0)
             {
                 printf("%d ",i);
             }
       }
      }
}
```

for this code i'm getting **presentation error** this is the first time i'm getting this type of error please suggest me how can i over come that problem

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message?

Comment: @Beta Ah, yes, an I tried to edit it, but another edit was waiting.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://ideone.com/26Nzsh) Please provide the error message (or a screenshot).

Comment: We cannot reproduce the error. What if you use a hard-coded value instead of scanning stdin? What if you omit the `printf` statement? [Simplify.](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: if give input:6 it shows like 1 2 3 6 . but actual output is 1 2 3 6.

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect for factor i think you miss some thing

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int n,i;
 printf("enter an integer value:");
 scanf("%d",&n);
if(n!=0)
 {
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       if(n%i==0)
         {
             printf("%d ",i);
         }
   }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error has nothing to do with your code

I ran the code I am not getting any errors:

Input

```
36
```

Ouput

```
enter an integer value:1 2 3 4 6 9 12 18 36
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine and i would suggest you to use

```
for(i=1;i*i<n;i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

for better performance and ofcourse any number is a factor of itself

Comment: He should actually change it to `i * i < n` which will result in O(log n) complexity rather than O(n).

Comment: @Marian i dont think that condition will result in all the factors.Example for testcase 50 your condition will result in 1 2 and 5 while the needed output is 1 2 5 10 25

Comment: You get two factors per iteration e.g 2 and 25, 5 and 10 etc.

Comment: ya you are right,was just thinking about it,will edit the answer.thanks :)